# Prepared Statement failing with DB2 SQL error

Tags: java, db2

I am trying to execute the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println();
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:port/database", username, password);
             connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            // String plsql = "BEGIN INSERT INTO t VALUES(42); COMMIT; END;";
            String plsql = "BEGIN UPDATE TABLE SET PROPERTY_VALUE='test6' where property_name='TEST'; COMMIT; END;";
            PreparedStatement pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(plsql);
            pstatement.execute();


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And i am getting following error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.co: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=END;NAME='TEST'; COMMIT;;END, DRIVER=3.53.70
```

How to resolve this issue. why prepared statement is supporting in this scenario?

Comment: You need to remove the very last semicolon, after `END`, from your statement.

Comment: I tried removing semicolon after END. Now I'm getting different error..

Comment: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.co: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=call BEGIN;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<labeled_begin_atomic>, DRIVER=3.53.70

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `commit` the transaction using the JDBC call to `connection.commit()`.

This [article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/commit-rollback.htm) gives you a good example.

Your code would change to something like below in the body

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
         System.out.println();
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:port/database", username, password);
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:port/database", username, password);
         connection.setAutoCommit(false);
         String plsql = "UPDATE AR01.REBILL_PROPERTIES SET PROPERTY_VALUE='test6' where property_name='TEST'";
         PreparedStatement pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(plsql);
         pstatement.executeUpdate();
         connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        connection.rollback();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.